# Why isn't my layout working?

Tags: css, debugging, layout

I need some help with a practice project I'm working on. I've got my content divs (.primary, .secondary and .tertiary) sat within a wrapper that's currently set to 100% width (for the sake of debugging).

I want it so that .primary and .secondary appear next to each other side by side at a screen size of 779px and above with tertiary set at 100% of the wrapper's width below them.

All three content divs also have the class col which I've floated left so in theory, I should be able to set .primary and .secondary to 50% and they should happily sit next to each other, right?

Wrong.

They sit as blocks below each other. Both have a width of exactly half of the wrapper (used dev tools in google chrome to check) but they won't sit next to each other until I sit their widths to 48% and then they leave a gap to their immediate right.

I honestly can't make heads or tails of it. I'm going to include the full code below for anyone that wants to just copy and paste to see the weirdness. I should note as well, there is a normalize file on there, downloaded from:  https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dragon Ball Fan Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <header class="main-header clearfix">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Dragon Ball Fan Site</h1>
          <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Main</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Manga</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Anime</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Video Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
    </header>

        <div class="banner">
          <img src="img/main-img.png" alt="Main Image, Goku" class="main-img">
          <h1 class="name">Dragon Ball Fansite</h1>
          <span class="tagline">A Site For Fans, By Fans</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="secondary col">
          <h2>Welcome</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel dui at odio imperdiet pulvinar vitae sed arcu. </p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel dui at odio imperdiet pulvinar vitae sed arcu. Cras accumsan leo nulla, at suscipit augue finibus ac. Aliquam ut mi vulputate, ullamcorper metus quis, tempor lorem. Praesent eleifend dignissim ligula. Nunc enim lectus, fringilla at odio vel, sagittis volutpat velit. Integer pretium ac nisl eget volutpat.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="primary col">
          <h2>About Dragon Ball</h2>
          <img src="img/cast.png" alt="Main Cast" class="cast">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel dui at odio imperdiet pulvinar vitae sed arcu. Cras accumsan leo nulla, at suscipit augue finibus ac. Aliquam ut mi vulputate, ullamcorper metus quis, tempor lorem.</p>
        </div>

          <div class="tertiary col">
            <h2>About Us</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
              <li>Ut vel dui at odio imperdiet pulvinar vitae sed arcu. Cras accumsan leo nulla, at suscipit augue finibus ac.</li>
              <li>Aliquam ut mi vulputate, ullamcorper metus quis, tempor lorem.</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <footer class="main-footer">
          <span class="copyright"> &copy;Dragon Ball Fan Site 2018</span>
        </footer>
  </body>
</html>

/* =========
Fonts
========= */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@@font-face {
  font-family: 'saiyain-sans';
  src: url(font/Saiyan-Sans.ttf);
}
/* =========
Elements
========= */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.441em;

}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.953em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

p {
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
}

/* =========
Classes
========= */

.main-header {
  text-align: center;
  color: #f85b1a;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.title {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.main-nav li {
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.main-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f85b1a;
  display: block;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f85b1a;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.main-img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.name {
  font-family: 'saiyain-sans', 'Roboto',  sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.primary,
.secondary {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.cast {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-footer {
  background-color: #072083;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.copyright {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #8a9294;
}

/* =========
media queries
========= */

@media (min-width: 779px) {

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-header {
  padding: 1em;
}

.title,
.col {
  float: left;
}

.title {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.main-nav {
  float: right;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
  border-right: 1px solid #8a9294;
}

.main-nav li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.name {
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.tagline {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;

}

.secondary,
.primary {
  width: 50%;
}

.copyright {
  padding: 2em;
}
/* =========
Clearfix
========= */

.clearfix::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  }
}
```

Comment: Divs default display is block, if you want them to be inline, change your div display property to inline

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. It was the border box property. Adding any padding and things like that were pushing it to be bigger than the wrap. I had the border property added to test where it was going wrong and that was just adding to the problem.

Thanks to everyone that took the time to look.